# Разделить переменную на 2 переменные в cmd

Tags: cmd, for

Обрабатываю строки в файле:
`For /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%i In ("%file%") Do (...)`

В файле содержатся строки с пробелом:

> 123456 123
> 865234 80
> 365842 1260

В строке **всегда только 2 слова** и разделены они **пробелом**.
**Вопрос:** Как переменную `%%i` разделить смотря **по пробелу** на 2 переменные, чтобы в дальнейшем работать с ними.

Например:

> %%i=123456 123
> ...
> echo !str1! -----123456
> echo !str2! -----123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For /F "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%i In ("%file%") Do (
    echo %%i 
    echo %%j
)
```

Если delims не указан - используется пробел/табуляция. Т.е. можно и `"usebackq tokens=1,2 delims= "` - указать строго пробел.

И с используемым разделителем забираем токены номер 1 и 2. Первый кладётся в переменную %%i, второй - в следующую по алфавиту, т.е. %%j.

---

Примечание. При использовании параметра usebackq - не используйте список разделителей!!! В CMD имеется баг, который приводит к неправильной обработке списка разделителей.

Comment: в который раз помогаете, спасибо

Comment: @MaksimMaslennikov Второй раз, вроде бы...

Comment: это уже много для меня